# Labels off-by-one with Bokeh hbar and ColumnDataSource

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have a `hbar`-plot driven by a `ColumnDataSource` with categorical labels on the y-axis and two numerical x-axes. In order to have two sets of bars per label on the y-axis, I construct two ranges (`Things1=df.Thing.index + 1 - 0.2` and `Things2=df.Thing.index + 1 + 0.2`) and assign the two `hbar`-instances to one of those ranges each.

This gives me the correct layout if and only if the ranges `Things1` and `Things2` in the `ColumnDataSource` are constructed with a predefined offset of 1; otherwise, all labels and bars are offset by exactly one entry.

The way I now construct the plot looks something like the following:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([('Store', 'Juice', 3, 19.0),
                       ('Warehouse', 'Paint', 7, 21.0),
                       ('Store', 'Fruit', 2, 6.0),
                       ('Warehouse', 'Grass', 4, 15.0),
                       ('Store', 'Leaves', 9, 32.0)],
                      columns=('Storage', 'Thing', 'Quantity', 'Valueation'))


source = bokeh.models.ColumnDataSource(dict(Quantity=df.Quantity,
                                            Things1=df.Thing.index + 1 - 0.2,  # Why +1 ?
                                            Things2=df.Thing.index + 1 + 0.2,  # Why +1 ?
                                            Valueation=df.Valueation,
                                            Storage=df.Storage))

plot = bokeh.plotting.figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=300,
                             y_range=list(df.Thing.unique()),
                             x_range=(0, df.Quantity.max() * 1.1))
plot.hbar(y='Things1', right='Quantity', height=0.3, alpha=0.7, source=source)
plot.hbar(y='Things2', right='Valueation', height=0.3, alpha=1, source=source,
          x_range_name="ValueationRange")
plot.yaxis.axis_label = 'Thing'
plot.xaxis.axis_label = 'Quantity'
plot.extra_x_ranges = {"ValueationRange":
                       bokeh.models.Range1d(start=0, end=df.Valueation.max() * 1.1)}
plot.add_layout(bokeh.models.LinearAxis(x_range_name="ValueationRange",
                                        axis_label='Valueation'), 'above')
bokeh.plotting.show(plot)
```

`Things1/2=df.Thing.index + 1 -/+ 0.2` gives the correct plot:

[image: Correct plot]

With `Things1/2=df.Thing.index -/+ 0.2` I get

[image: Wrong plot]

My guess is that this is due to the different ranges being 0- or 1-based. Is this a simple gotcha or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Hi, It is my problem to hide axis such as "Leaves", "Grass", ... Is there any solution in Bokeh ColumnDataSource ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT Turns out that this use of raw values (as opposed to true categorical data) with factor range is not documented and untested. The handling of categorical data will be changing in 0.12.7, which will allow the functionality desired with properly using categorical data - see bigreddots (lead bokeh dev) comments below.**

From just observation, it does seem that the default behaviour of categorical ranges is to map integer y values from 1 onwards to the categories.

If you add the y_range after initialising the plot object, the raw ticks are exposed:
[image: plot no label]

So as you mentioned, its just due to the ranges. The first plotted data series starts at 0 but the first label from 1. You can either set the offset or map explicit y ticks to values with a functickformatter, which gives exact control over mapping between values and labels.

If you look at an example such as http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/categorical.html, you can see that the data is mapped to the categories but that is because the y values are entered as factors themselves. In your example you are just changing the y axis but to offset the values you cant use the raw categories themselves.

*As an aside:*
**EDIT the offset attribute may not exist in 0.12.7 so it is likely best not to rely on it/ assuming it will exist.**

Looking at the docs it says the default offset is 0. So i think you would want an offset of -1 to account for this. See http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/ranges.html#bokeh.models.ranges.FactorRange.offset

```
import pandas

import bokeh
import bokeh.models, bokeh.plotting

df = pandas.DataFrame([('Store', 'Juice', 3, 19.0),
                       ('Warehouse', 'Paint', 7, 21.0),
                       ('Store', 'Fruit', 2, 6.0),
                       ('Warehouse', 'Grass', 4, 15.0),
                       ('Store', 'Leaves', 9, 32.0)],
                      columns=('Storage', 'Thing', 'Quantity', 'Valueation'))


source = bokeh.models.ColumnDataSource(dict(Quantity=df.Quantity,
                                            Things1=df.Thing.index - 0.2,  # Why +1 ?
                                            Things2=df.Thing.index + 0.2,  # Why +1 ?
                                            Valueation=df.Valueation,
                                            Storage=df.Storage))

plot = bokeh.plotting.figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=300,
                             y_range=list(df.Thing.unique()),
                             x_range=(0, df.Quantity.max() * 1.1))

plot.y_range.offset = -1

plot.hbar(y='Things1', right='Quantity', height=0.3, alpha=0.7, source=source)
plot.hbar(y='Things2', right='Valueation', height=0.3, alpha=1, source=source,
          x_range_name="ValueationRange")
plot.yaxis.axis_label = 'Thing'
plot.xaxis.axis_label = 'Quantity'
plot.extra_x_ranges = {"ValueationRange":
                       bokeh.models.Range1d(start=0, end=df.Valueation.max() * 1.1)}
plot.add_layout(bokeh.models.LinearAxis(x_range_name="ValueationRange",
                                        axis_label='Valueation'), 'above')
bokeh.plotting.show(plot)
```

Comment: Please be aware the handling of categoricals is changing in next Bokeh release, and the `offset` property may be removed entirely. The officially supported way to provide categorical coordinates is to use the actual categories, not to try and give the synthetic coordinates directly. That this works is accidental and undocumented.

Comment: So is best practice to not use a factor range, and map the y axis labels with a FuncTickFormatter? then the data is not truly categorical, but just a relabeling of the y axis is achieved. Otherwise offsetting the actual values would be required like the poster is attempting

Comment: There is no reason not to use real categorical i.e `FactorRange`. Categoricals can be offset in `0.12.6` and earlier with the goofy `"foo:0.2"` syntax. In `0.12.7` there will be support for true nested categoricals so that offsetting won't be needed at all just to get grouping, and even when offsetting is needed it will be with `["foo", 0.2]` which is a much more robust syntax.

Comment: But `0.12.7` will also add support for putting padding in between groups of categoricals (e.g so grouped bars can be more group-y) In which case the mapping from categorical to synthetic coordinate is not so straightforward at all (and also computed in the browser), so that's another reason to prefer using real factors for categorical coordinates.

Comment: Cool, I'll delete mine as yours if more in depth. Lastly just to add, re: FuncTickFormatter That can be an OK route too, but I'd only personally do that if I wanted complete control over the mapping from "categories" to "synthetic coordinates". I don't think it is the first approach to reach for.

Comment: Can you provide an example for `FactorRange` with two or more `hbar`s per category in 0.12.6 ?

Comment: Well your example is using a FactorRange implicitly. The only other option is to use a FuncTickFormatter.